# find the probablity of going to picnic.

Tags: probability

Tomorrow Jim arranged a picnic.He invited Lily.the picnic can be held in a rainy or a sunny day.If it is a

rainy day, p(lily will attend the picnic)=20%.

If it is a sunny day,p(lily will attend the picnic)=80%.

P(tomorrow will be a rainy day)=40%.

what is the probability that Lily will attend the picnic?

Comment: There is a notion called "the law of total probability". Does that ring any bells? Have you heard about it?

Comment: Tomorrow : still confinement time, not time to go to picnic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be event Lily will attend a picnic and $S$ tommorow will be sunny.

So you have

$$\begin{align}
P(L) &=  P((L\cap S)\cup (L\cap S'))\\ 
&=  P(L\cap S)+P(L\cap S')\\
& =  P(L|S)\cdot P(S)+P(L|S')\cdot P(S')\\
&= 0,8\cdot 0,6+ 0,2\cdot 0,4\\
&=...
\end{align}$$